# How to animate sections in pure CSS when scrolling the page?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to animate (with `@keyframes`, `transform`...) some elements when the user scrolls the page. For example:

- When offset is 0: `div` has `height: 100px`.
- When offset is between 0 and 100: `div` is `height: 50px` and `color: blue`.
- And so on...

Is is possible using pure CSS?
If it is not, what are the most efficient ways to do it with HTML or Javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most efficient way to animate an element's style properties depending on scroll position will probably be to add a class with a scroll function:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kn4o0ke3/1/)**

```js
myID = document.getElementById("myID");

var myScrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y > 500) {
    // myID.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; // you can add individual styles 
    myID.className = "blue" // or add classes
  } else {
    // myID.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    myID.className = "red"
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

```css
body {
  height: 1100px;
}
#myID {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  animation: myAnimation 1s both;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
@keyframes myAnimation {
  0% {
    border-radius: 0px;
    line-height: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="red">Hello world</div>
```

Docs:

[.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)
[.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)
[.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Maybe it could work better with "transition" instead of the "@keyframes", doesn't it?

Comment: @Davdriver I added the animation just to show that you could, but yes a transition will work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Methinnks it's not possible to 'spy' scroll with pure css. If you want, you can do this with jQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var pos = parseInt($(document).scrollTop())

    if(pos == 0) {
        $('.yourDivClass').css({
            height : '100px' , 
            color : '#fff'
        })
    }

    if (pos > 0 && pos <= 100) {
        $('.yourDivClass').css({
            height : '50px' , 
            color : 'blue'
        })
    }   

    console.log(pos)
})
```

and of course if you wanna get a smooth transition, you supposed to declare transitions in your css file

```
.yourDivClass {
    transition: height 0.5s ease
}
```

Comment: I know that way, but I asked if is it possible to to without plugins, only with pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling is an event. Once you scroll the page, the event gets triggered and something happens. You cannot control events using Pure CSS. Period.

Some people would argue that even `:hover` is an event. Yes, and it is for some strange reason, implemented in CSS, but not others.

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS: no.

But you can have a class with keyframed animation associated with it, and then say when the element is [scrolled into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837772/jquery-how-can-i-trigger-an-event-when-a-div-comes-into-view), to add the class to the element. This will make it start doing the animation.

Comment: I saw that page before, but would like to use only pure JS, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) to set what happens when you reach a specific element of a page.

Comment: I would like to use only pure JS, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can check on scroll if the current position is greater than the scroll offset and the height of the element youre scrolling past.