# Show hidden element when scroll on custom div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page like this:

```
----------------------
.header
----------------------


.content
   .hidden-element (fixed right side)


----------------------
.footer
----------------------
```

I want to show the hidden element when you only scroll on content section.

For example you start to scroll down from header section. When you come to content section, hidden element will appear. If you scroll down again and come to footer section, hidden element will be hidden again.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837772/jquery-how-can-i-trigger-an-event-when-a-div-comes-into-view

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {

                $('.myDiv').hide(1000);
            }
            else {
                $('.myDiv').show(1000);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <br />
    <div style="height:400px"></div>

    <div class="myDiv">
        <ul>
            <li>Arunachal Pradesh</li>
            <li>Himachal Pradesh</li>
            <li>Uttar Pradesh</li>
            <li>Madhya Pradesh</li>
            <li>Andhra Pradesh</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div style="height:1000px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

please check the above code
this sample code is so easy 2 main functionn 
$(window).scroll()
is detect scroll event of page
if($(this).scrollTop() > 300)
check the pixel of scrolling from top of page when is more than 300 then hide the div or show the div in else condition.

Comment: I guess without an explanation this is not helpful at all

Comment: @Traxstar i hope my explatation help you